# Delphi 11 Problem with setting breakpoints

Tags: delphi

I have been using Delphi 7 for some time now. A combination of looking for answers on SO and various helpful comments have convinced me to download Delphi 11 Alexandria CE. I am in the process of updating all my old programs but one thing is slowing me down. I cannot use Breakpoints as I was used to by just clicking on the blue dot. because it doesn't work. I have tried to understand  Rad Studio's explanation and I understand (I think) that I want a Source breakpoint but I cannot set one. Could someone explain in simple terms how I can achieve this? I would be most grateful.

Comment: Are you in Debug mode, and not in Release mode? Do you run the app with the debugger and not without? The shortcuts for toggling a breakpoint (F5) and running the app with debugger attached (F9) haven't changed in the past.

Comment: Thank you  both for your help. I can now debug more easily

Comment: The clickable area to set a breakpoint has indeed moved a (little) bit in the last version of Delphi 11. That was discussed on some forum, but unfortunately I cannot find the reference now. It had to do with the changes to the API that can be used to extend IDE functionality.